# How to enable HTTP console on MongoDB 2.6 replica set

Tags: mongodb

I'm running a 3 server MongoDB replica set. I recently upgraded from 2.4 to 2.6.

On 2.4 I was able to reach the HTTP Console on all three servers, regardless of whether they were Primary or Secondary. Now with 2.6 there is a different config setting needed to enable the console.

```
# Disable the HTTP interface (Defaults to localhost:28017).
#nohttpinterface = true
nohttpinterface = false
```

If I create a completely fresh, standalone instance with 2.6, it works. However on the replica set, it does not. MongoDB is running on 27017 and I have confirmed nothing is running on 28017, so that rules out firewall issues.

Are there additional changes required to enable this feature on a replica set?

Comment: Where you able to make the HTTP Console work on 2.6? I've been unable to make it work even with a fresh install.

Answer (score 6):

Adding

```
httpinterface=true
```

in /etc/mongod.conf enables it on `http://127.0.0.1:28017`
I had to add

```
rest=true
```

to enable REST interface so that commands in http console are working.

Answer (score 3):

For mongodb v3.0.2 the mongod.conf is a yaml file,
you should add these two lines after net:

```
http.enabled: true
http.RESTInterfaceEnabled: true
```

my mongod.conf is

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

  http.enabled: true
  http.RESTInterfaceEnabled: true
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/

HTTP Status Interface

Deprecated since version 3.2: Starting in 3.2, MongoDB deprecates the HTTP interface.