# MongoDB Web server not available

Tags: mongodb

I've read that you can get some administrative information about your Mongo database by opening a web browser and going to http://localhost:28017. However once started mongod (2.6 on Windows) there is no port open on 28017 nor in another range. Is this feature still available in MongoDB ?
Thanks

Comment: At least the [**docs**](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-console) still say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll work if you start mongod with `--rest`. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039869/724972)

Answer (score 1):

you need to start mongod (in /bin directory) by enabling the REST API.

For windows: `mongod.exe --rest`

For linux : `./mongod --rest`

Find more details here.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--rest